# Weird empty cells in TableView using NSFetchResultController

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uitableview

I am currently programming an application using UITableView and NSFetchResultController to manage the tableview.

I must change my predicate several times. It work fine but some times, when tableview reload, some cell aren't filled.

At the end, my tableview present for example : 1 good cell, 2 empty cells, 3 good cells, 1 empty cells.
My database is not corrupted because when i touch a cell, the application get the good data to handle in database.

The bug is difficult to reproduce and make me crazy.

Here is my code :

**The fonction to load the request each time i must change the categorie**

```
//On charge la datasource
func loadFetchContoller(categorie: Categorie) {

    //On set le fetchRequest
    if self.fetchRequest == nil {
        self.fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "New")
    }

    //On tri par date de publication
    var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "published_at", ascending: false)
    self.fetchRequest!.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    //self.fetchRequest!.fetchBatchSize = 20

    //On met à jour le predicate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categorie.name = %@", categorie.name)
    self.fetchRequest!.predicate = predicate

    //Si le fetchResultController n'existe pas, on le crée
    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: self.fetchRequest!, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

    //On relance le fetchController
    var error: NSError?
    self.fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
    self.tableViewNews.reloadData()

}
```

**Here, fonctions of NSFetchedResultsController**

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableViewNews.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableViewNews.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .None)
    case .Update:
        if let cell = self.tableViewNews.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) {
            self.tableViewNews.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    case .Move:
        self.tableViewNews.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .None)
        self.tableViewNews.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .None)

    case .Delete:
        self.tableViewNews.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .None)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableViewNews.endUpdates()
}
```

**And finally, fonctions to handle TableView :**

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //On retourne le nombre de données
    if let arraySection = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections {
        return arraySection[section].numberOfObjects
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    //On récupère la new
    var new = self.fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! New

    //Si on est sur les photos, on retourne tous le temps la même taille
    if new.media == "photo" {
        return 220.0
    }
        //Sinon on calcule la hauteur des strings à afficher
    else {

        //On récupère le texte final de la description
        var lengthDescription = new.description_new.stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText().length()
        if lengthDescription > 200 {
            lengthDescription = 200
        }

        //On récupère la description et on regarde la hauteur du texte que l'on va afficher
        var description = FBAHelperController.sharedInstance.getDateInText(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: new.published_at.doubleValue)) + " - " + (new.description_new.stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText() as NSString).substringToIndex(lengthDescription) + "..."
        var heightTitre = new.title.heightForString(new.title, font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 18.0)!, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 60)
        var heightDescription = new.description_new.heightForString(description, font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17.0)!, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 20)
        return heightTitre + heightDescription + 95.0
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //On récupère la new
    var new = self.fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! New

    //CELLULE AVEC PHOTO
    if new.media == "photo" {

        //On crée la cellule
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FBATeamInfoWithImageTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FBATeamInfoWithImageTableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
        //CELLULE SANS PHOTO
    else {

        //On crée la cellule
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FBATeamInfoWithoutImageTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FBATeamInfoWithoutImageTableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**configureCell()** is the fonction I use to fill the cell (label, imageview, etc...à

Comment: So... Are you using Objective-C or Swift? Or both?

Comment: I am using Swift. Can it be the cause of my problem ?

Comment: Then why are you tagging this question with objective-c?

Comment: Because i accept answer related to Objective C. I think it can be useful. But i can remove the objective C flag if needed

Comment: can u pls provide some code

Comment: can you show us how do you set the related informations to the UITableViewCell?